# Is there any way to restrict usage of internet for specific application?

Tags: android

For this we list all installed app's from device then select some apps from this list to block internet usage so that internet will be blocked for the selected application. If user will remove selected app's then it can access internet, so anyone have any idea for this?.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately its not possible for a normal app. Only user has the control over it. At best, you can redirect user to the settings where he/she can disable the internet connection for that app.

One alternative would be to implement VPN service in your app and try to control the network access.

Comment: Thank you @Sagar..for vpn also we have to create vpn server for it right? so i think it will be awkward.

Comment: There are different Apps available in market which do this without need of root access. You can check how they are doing this